# Web push notifications characters limits across different browsers

Tags: cross-browser, web-push

I want to implement web push notification in my application, however I'm stuck at very simple problem: is there anywhere on the internet resource which would give me complete table for characters limits in web push notification for notification title and body for different browsers/operating systems (I'm interested in Android/Windows 10/macOS and Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Edge, Opera and Yandex browsers)? I've spend quite a lot of time looking over various pages on the internet, however data I encountered there was either incomplete or not up to date or event mutually exclusive between various resources.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't find any information, because **the standard doesn't set a limit**.

The text, when too long, is **automatically truncated** by the browser. The actual limit depends on many variables: the OS, the browser, the layout, the presence of notification fields like images and action buttons.

The only actual limit is the total payload (which includes all fields and the JSON): you should stay below **3kB**.

**Update**: I have made some research for you on the practical limits for each browser and published the results in this [blog post](https://blog.pushpad.xyz/2020/03/web-push-notifications-character-limit/).

Comment: But there are different limits in certain browsers/operating systems. I'm looking for complete data about limits (by limit I mean number of characters before text gets truncated) for browsers/OS I listed in my question.

Comment: @Furman I think that it depends on too many variables and that is going to change with every browser / OS release. I think that your best option is to simply try to send a notification to Chrome on Android, for example, which has a large market share, and see how many characters it display